# How to connect to local Mysql server from mobile using j2me

Tags: php, database, java-me, mobile

I'm developing mobile application which will be able to download/upload mobile phone book contact from mysql database which is stored on my pc at localhost. I know to how to get contact numbers from/to the mobile phone & save them on the database, but I don't know how to locate to the local Mysql server (i.e http://localhost), I'm using wamp 2.0 for windows & MIDP 2.0 for mobile.Anyone please help me with the steps or procedure.

Thanking You,
Rittwick Banerjee

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql database is published on localhost only then there is no way your mobile app will be able to connect to it.

My suggestion, you need a ISP that supports mysql and publish your database first, as a start.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such thing as mysql functions in j2me.

only a [record store](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/Readandwritetotherecordstore.htm) where you can put bytearrays which you can read in a loop not even with some key value scheme.

however you can do [http connections](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/HttpConnection.htm) so you could build your api that runs on a webserver.

i am really amazed that anybody is really still using j2me :D it is totally buggy, the latest developement kit was shit and didnt even run under 64 bit or linux.

and nowadays no device supports it anymore. only android and ios are relevant imo.

Comment: Then what technology on platform or whatever to use when you are planning to develop a software that will run on a wide range of mobile phones.